# How to verify a phone number?

Tags: android

The problem that I have is the SMS gateway not working very well when I need to verify the phone number. I'm using Clickatell Sometimes working, sometimes no. Users are very angry with us because the request the sms and they never receive it. I need a service or another way to verify the phone number efficiently. The problem is the users country (south and center America like argentina, uruguay, paraguay, ecuador, panama, etc). The most of t he SMS gateway not working righ in this kind of country. Another alternative? May be a phone call or something. Thanks!

Comment: Please check on [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/127269) and [this](https://www.quora.com/Online-Banking-What-is-the-best-possible-alternative-to-OTP-One-Time-Password-sent-in-SMS-mode), Hope the second link will help you, which eventually redirects to [this](https://www.cognalys.com/) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter's digits (https://get.digits.com/) is one of the best ways to check user validation through the phone number (SMS OTP) and it's totally FREE. :)

Digits are powered by Twitter’s infrastructure. Take seconds to integrate with your project. Just download the fabric plugin for android studio from digit website.